# Upgrading to EntityFramework 6.1.3 and now receiving context exceptions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I recently upgraded from Entity Framework 5 to Entity Framework 6.1.3.

The below code using multiple contexts of the same connection worked fine before in EF5:

```
var Ids = MyDbContext.MyObject.Select(x => x.Id).Take(5).AsEnumerable();
var myObjects = MyDbContext2.MyObject.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

In EF6, I receive:

> The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are
>   associated with different contexts. Description: An unhandled
>   exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
>   Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and
>   where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: The specified LINQ
>   expression contains references to queries that are associated with
>   different contexts.

What in Entity Framework changed to stop this from working? Is there anyway I can get this to work without changing code?

Answer (score 2):

Change first line from `.AsEnumerable()` to `.ToList()`.

Comment: Right, but that's not what I am asking. This is one instance of a runtime error in a large solution.

Comment: @user90279 Are you sure it was not some extension allowing to do such queries in EF5 ?

Comment: I am fairly confident. I created a barebones unit test for both versions of EF and it's still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx#_Query_Plan_Caching

According to this documentation, there were changes made to `Contains` processing in EF 6 to optimize the way the underlying SQL query is generated.

Just a shot in the dark without looking at EF6's code:

IEnumerable is generally a deferred execution that doesn't hit the database until you reference the data in some way.  From the framework's point of view, that isn't a list of integers or longs, but a query that needs to be performed in a different context.  Since it's in the middle of a query in a different context, the SQL parser is probably having trouble resolving it with their new way of doing things.  IEnumerable is a sort of half way state between Queryable and loaded.  I'd guess whatever changes they made for optimization do not perform the outstanding queries any longer, and it just immediately short circuits to an exception if the referenced object isn't part of the context, no matter what it is.

This is also why changing it to a `List()` allows it to work.  You're working off of a list of primitives and not an unresolved query.

Why did they make the change? I suppose they have their reasons (even beyond optimization).  One I can think of is that it prevents the query generation parts from modifying the loaded state of that IEnumerable to remove that possibly unwanted side effect.

Comment: You may be on to something: entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/245

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `ToDictionary()`:

```
var Ids = (
  from x in MyDbContext.MyObject.Select()
  where x.Contains(x.Id)
  select x
).ToDictionary(x => x.Key).Keys.ToList();

var myObjects = (
  from y in MyDbContext2.MyObject
  where y => Ids.Contains(y.Id).ToList()
).ToList();

return myObjects;
```